# as3 getting the "hours" in milliseconds in mp3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, datetime, time

In As3 the code below gets the minutes and the seconds:

```
var minutes:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000 / 60);
var seconds:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000) % 60;
```

But what if your listening to an audio talk that goes over the hour mark?

**What is the math needed to get the hours from an mp3 talk?**

```
 var hours:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000) % 60    & (((???????)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `PrayPrayer.position` is in milliseconds.  Your `minutes` line is dividing by 1000 to get seconds, then dividing by 60 to go from seconds to minutes.  Your `seconds` line is looking at the remainder.

What you started in your `hours` line is using `%`, so will look at the remainder - you're using seconds there.  `%` is the modulo operator.  It gives you the remainder of integer division.  So your line

```
var seconds:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000) % 60;
```

is finding the number of seconds (PrayPrayer.position / 1000), which could be something big like 2337, dividing by 60 and just keeping the remainder.  2337/60 = 38 remainder 57, so 2337%60 will be 57.

An easy way to find hours is to use the same trick with your minutes.

```
var minutes:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000 / 60);
var seconds:uint = Math.floor(PrayPrayer.position / 1000) % 60;
var hours:uint = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
minutes %= 60;  // same as minutes = minutes % 60.  Forces minutes to be between 0 and 59.
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my conversion method:

```
    public static var MINUTE:Number = 60;
    public static var HOUR:Number = 60 * MINUTE;
    public static var DAY:Number = 24 * HOUR;

        /**
     * returns string created from seconds value in following format hours:minutes:seconds, i.e. 121 seconds will be displayed as 00:02:01
     * @param   seconds <i>Number</i>
     * @return <i>String</i>
     */
    public static function secondsToHMS(seconds:Number, doNotRound:Boolean = false):String
    {
        var _bNegative:Boolean = seconds < 0;

        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);

        var time:Number = (doNotRound) ? seconds:Math.round(seconds);

        var ms:Number;
        var msec:String;

        if (doNotRound)
        {
            ms = seconds - (seconds | 0);
            msec = prependZeros((ms * 1000) | 0, 3);
        }


        var sec:Number = (time | 0) % MINUTE;

        var min:Number = Math.floor((time / MINUTE) % MINUTE);

        var hrs:Number = Math.floor(time / HOUR);
        //
        return (_bNegative ? "-":"") +
               ((hrs > 9) ? "":"0") + hrs + ":" +
               ((min > 9) ? "":"0") + min + ":" +
               ((sec > 9) ? "":"0") + sec +
               (doNotRound ? "." + msec:"");
    }
```

prependZeros is another utility to add "0" in front of given string.